# Angular subscribing to a service BehabiourSubject inside the service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to subscribe to `currentTheme` BehaviorSubject inside the service itself

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ThemeService {
  currentTheme: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    this.currentTheme = new BehaviorSubject<string>('dark');
    this.currentTheme.subscribe((theme) => {
      let themeLink = this.document.getElementById(
        'app-theme'
      ) as HTMLLinkElement;
        console.log(theme)
      if (themeLink) themeLink.href = `mdc-${theme}-indigo.css`;
    });
  }
}
```

Although I'm not getting any error but is it a good practice to `subscribe` inside the `service` itself, or should I move the logic to the `component` where I trigger change of the `BehaviorSubject` value ?

**Edit 1**

I will always have the element with id `app-theme` as I define it in `index.html`

```
<link id="app-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mdc-dark-indigo.css">
```

**Edit 2**

I've declared `currentTheme` as `BehaviorSubject` as I have some other components apart from ThemeSwitcher to load some assets and perform other operations.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `app-theme`  html element is present when the service is initialized. If you are doing dom-related things you do it in an appropriate lifecycle hook and instead accessing directly the element using an angular way would be better.

Comment: Edited the question, I will always have the element with id `app-theme` as I define it in `index.html`

Comment: Well, then `currentTheme` field should be private and you should expose methods for changing the theme. And one more thing about the theme thing: since the theme element resides inside `index.html` what will happen when a user selects another theme? Will your application load with the default theme and then the settings will be applied from some storage?

Comment: In angular assets I'm having 2 theme files for switching between them, so that is why I was subscribing to change of `currentTheme` BehaviorSubject.

Comment: With this construct, why do you need a subject at all? I imagine you would call ithe service.currentTheme.onNext method with the theme? Then you can just turn the subscribe block to a normal method taking a theme string and get rid of all the async hassle?

Comment: Edited the question, I need it as subject as I'm using it in other component, so @Loop in your opinion I should not subscribe inside the service and rather have a function call to change theme?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a subject at all

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ThemeService {
  private themeLink = this.document.getElementById('app-theme') as HTMLLinkElement;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  setTheme(theme: string) {
    this.themeLink.href = `mdc-${theme}-indigo.css`;
  }
}
```

A behavior subject would be useful if multiple thing needed to happen with the theme is changed, different component could subscribe to the observable for notification of a theme change and the menu component could rerender etc. But when you have a single thing to do such as change a single link then just change that link, no need for an observable.

Comment: Edited the question, I need it as behavior subject as I'm using it in other components, in that case how do you suggest to write the logic?

Comment: Then I would probably just have a behavior subsect and a set method for the service and do DOM manipulation in a component, for something like a CSS theme in index.html maybe the app component.